# Moving an <img> element across table cells?

Tags: javascript, html

I’m trying to create a program where you first click on the “Step” button, the `<p>` element inside the top left cell should be replaced by an `<img>` element, i.e. an `<img>` element of your choice.

With all subsequent clicks of the “Step” button, this image is moved one cell forward clockwise along the *perimeter* cells of the table. When the image moves out of a cell, the original text of this cell should be restored. Clicking on the “Reset” button should restore the page back to its initial state.

Note: alternatively, you can add `<p>` only to perimeter cells of table and write text directly inside `<td>` elements for cells not on the table perimenter.

Any help would be appreciated!

Here is a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bbzmLd7p/43/) with comment code to explain why I did things.

```js
function moveImageAlongCells() { //Function to move the image along the cells
  var table = document.getElementById('myTable');

  reset(table);

  var img = document.createElement("IMG"); //create the image
  
  img.setAttribute("src", "img_pulpit.jpg"); //Example from internet

  for (var r = 0, n = table.rows.length; r < n; r++) {
    for (var c = 0, m = table.rows[r].cells.length; c < m; c++) {
      // alert(table.rows[r].cells[c].innerHTML); // This worked as it went across all the the cells
      temp = table.rows[r].cells[c];
      table.rows[r].cells[c].removechild("P"); //Do I remove the <P> element?
      table.rows[r].celss[c].appendChild("img"); // And then add the <img> element
    }
  }
}

function reset(old) {
  document.getElement(old); //Trying to save the table without edits so that the reset button works
}
```

```css
table, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<p>Click the Step button and it will move the image over to the next cell all the way along the PERIMETER of the cell. The reset button then will reset the table back to normal. With no images</p>

<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>Row1 cell1</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>Row1 cell2</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>Row1 cell3</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>Row1 cell4</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>Row2 cell1</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>Row2 cell2</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>Row2 cell3</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>Row2 cell4</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>Row3 cell1</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>Row3 cell2</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>Row3 cell3</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>Row3 cell4</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>Row4 cell1</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>Row4 cell2</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>Row4 cell3</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>Row4 cell4</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>

<!-- calls the function that moves the image -->
<button onclick="moveImageAlongCells()">STEP</button>

<!-- resets the table to it's original form. (without any images) -->
<button onclick="reset()">RESET</button>
```

Comment: What is the problem? This is easy! For ur reputation it should be very easy.

Comment: Sure it's easy but for me it hasn't clicked yet. I've tried dozens of ways and can't seem to make it work. Seemingly reached a dead end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make the image go around the perimeter you need to check its current position at each step and compare it to the table boundaries.

Also at each step you need to keep the current cell and the previous child `<p>` element.

Try this example:

```js
var table = document.getElementById('myTable');
var img = document.createElement("IMG"); //create the image
img.setAttribute("src", "http://images.clipartpanda.com/circle-clip-art-niBB6kXiA.png");
var temp;
var row = 0, column = 0;
var currentCell;

function moveImageAlongCells() { //Function to move the image along the cells
  if (temp) {
    currentCell.removeChild(currentCell.firstElementChild);
    currentCell.appendChild(temp);
  }
  currentCell = table.rows[row].cells[column];
  temp = currentCell.firstElementChild;
  if (row === 0 && column < table.rows[0].cells.length - 1) {
    column++;
  } else if (column === table.rows[0].cells.length - 1 && row < table.rows.length - 1) {
    row++;
  } else if (row === table.rows.length - 1 && column > 0) {
    column--;
  } else {
    row--;
  }
  currentCell.removeChild(currentCell.firstElementChild);
  currentCell.appendChild(img);
}

function reset() {
  if (currentCell && temp) {
    currentCell.removeChild(currentCell.firstElementChild);
    currentCell.appendChild(temp);
    row = 0;
    column = 0;
  }
}
```

```css
table, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
img {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: relative;
  left: calc(50% - 10px);
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>Row1 cell1</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>Row1 cell2</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>Row1 cell3</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>Row1 cell4</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>Row2 cell1</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>Row2 cell2</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>Row2 cell3</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>Row2 cell4</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>Row3 cell1</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>Row3 cell2</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>Row3 cell3</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>Row3 cell4</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>Row4 cell1</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>Row4 cell2</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>Row4 cell3</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>Row4 cell4</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>

<!-- calls the function that moves the image -->
<button onclick="moveImageAlongCells()">STEP</button>

<!-- resets the table to it's original form. (without any images) -->
<button onclick="reset()">RESET</button>
```

Comment: Was my use of the parameter in the reset function not needed? Other than that your code is easy to follow and I'm trying to see why and how it does what it does. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @newbs Yes, your reset function parameter was not needed considering that you never passed it. My reset function uses the outer `currentCell` and `temp` variables to restore the page state. If you have any questions regarding my code, I'll be glad to help!

Comment: Okay that makes sense. Thank you so much. It makes loads of sense now. If i see anything I have a question with I'll let you know :D

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution:

```js
nr_cells = $("#myTable").find('td').length;
position = 0;
$(".next").click(function(i, v) {
  console.log(i + " " + position);

  $("#myTable").find('td').each(function(i, v) {
    
    if (i == position) {
      $(v).append('<img class="irc_mi" src="https://img.stockfresh.com/img/header-avatar.jpg" style="z-index:99999" width="50" height="50">');
      $(v).find('p').css('display', 'none');

    }

     $("#myTable").find('td').each(function(i, v) {
      if(i != position && nr_cells != i+1) {
       $(v).find('img').remove();
      $(v).find('p').css('display', 'block');
      }
    });
   
  });
  position++;
  
   
});

$(".reset").click(function(i, v) {

  $("#myTable").find('td').each(function(i, v) {

    $(v).find('img').remove();
    $(v).find('p').css('display', 'block');

  });
  position = 0;
});
```

```css
table,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  Click the Step button and it will move the image over to the next cell all the way along the PERIMETER of the cell. The reset button then will reset the table back to normal. With no images</p>

<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>Row1 cell1</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>Row1 cell2</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>Row1 cell3</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>Row1 cell4</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>Row2 cell1</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>Row2 cell2</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>Row2 cell3</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>Row2 cell4</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>Row3 cell1</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>Row3 cell2</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>Row3 cell3</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>Row3 cell4</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>Row4 cell1</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>Row4 cell2</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>Row4 cell3</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>Row4 cell4</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button class="next">Next</button>
<button class="reset">Reset</button>
```

Comment: This looks promising, but the image stays in the previous cell instead of reverting it as it moves to the next. Wouldn't saving the cell content to a temp variable make the image look like it's moving?

Answer (score 1):

Edited: Make image cover whole table data cell

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="no-js">
<!--<![endif]-->

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
        table,
        td {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }

        td{
            width: 70px;
        }

        img{
            width: 100%;
        }

        .hidden {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
            <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="#">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->
    <p>Click the Step button and it will move the image over to the next cell all the way along the PERIMETER of the cell. The
        reset button then will reset the table back to normal. With no images</p>

    <table id="myTable">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>Row1 cell1</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>Row1 cell2</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>Row1 cell3</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>Row1 cell4</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>Row2 cell1</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>Row2 cell2</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>Row2 cell3</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>Row2 cell4</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>Row3 cell1</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>Row3 cell2</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>Row3 cell3</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>Row3 cell4</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>Row4 cell1</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>Row4 cell2</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>Row4 cell3</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>Row4 cell4</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br>

    <!-- calls the function that moves the image -->
    <button id="step">STEP</button>

    <!-- resets the table to it's original form. (without any images) -->
    <button id="reset">RESET</button>
    <script>
        var table = document.getElementById('myTable')
        var tdInTable = table.getElementsByTagName('td')
        var image = document.createElement('img')
        image.setAttribute('src', 'https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/logopedia/images/2/26/Research%40Google_Icon.png')
        var step = document.getElementById('step')
        var reset = document.getElementById('reset')
        var index = 0
        step.addEventListener('click', function () {
            if(index === 0){
                tdInTable[tdInTable.length - 1].getElementsByTagName('p')[0].classList.remove('hidden')

            }
            if (index > 0) {
                tdInTable[index - 1].getElementsByTagName('p')[0].classList.remove('hidden')
            }
            tdInTable[index].getElementsByTagName('p')[0].classList.add('hidden')
            tdInTable[index].appendChild(image)
            index++

            if (index >= tdInTable.length) {
                index = 0

            }
        })

        reset.addEventListener('click', function () {
            if(image.parentElement){
            tdInTable[--index].removeChild(image)
            tdInTable[index].getElementsByTagName('p')[0].classList.remove('hidden')
            index = 0
            }

        })
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is amazing! I see what you did and it makes sense. Is there away to make it so the image only goes around the perimeter?

Answer (score 0):

**Not the solution but steps to tackle this type of problem.**

Separate the dom manipulation or `View` logic from your `State`. `State` means what content you have, what is the text in `(2,4)th` cell or image in
 `(4,2)th` cell, is it showing text or image. And then `View` should be rendered based on that `State`.

**Steps.**

1. Create a state for every cell in table. Example

   ```
   class CellState {
     constructor() {
     this.showText = true;
     this.text = 'bla bla';
     this.imgSrc = 'http...';
   }}
   ```

You will have a `CellState[][]` to track all cells. Let there be `function init()` which initialise the `CellState[][]` to default value.

2. Create a function `render()` which  renders based on cell state. Say for 16 cells it iterates. If `showText` is `true` then text is shown else image.
   If there is input for text then changing the value  on input should change that `CellState` text.
3. Now there should be two event: `Step` and `Reset`.

Reset should look like this

```
function onClickReset(){
  init(); //again init.
  render();
}
```

Step should look like this

```
function onClickStep() {

  // handle your complex logic of changing or shifting the image etc.. 
  // or whatever you want to achieve.
  // But we won't have to modify the dom elements just the CellState[][],
  // as the dom manipulation will be automatically done in render();

  render();
}
```

Don't worry about any performance.